# When does the change of coordinates of a turtle becomes effective using setxy?

Tags: coordinates, netlogo

If I write:

```
to go
some code...
ask turtles[
    turtle-function
]
tick
end
;;previous coordinates : 2 2
to turtle-function
    setxy 3 5
    ask patch-at 1 0
    [
        some code...
    ]

end
```

Has the "patch-at 1 0" got (4 5) as coordinates or has it got (3 2) as coordinates?

The point is: Is the coordinates' update done after or before "tick"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been easy to find out by yourself. If you replace:

```
ask patch-at 1 0
[
    some code...
]
```

with:

```
ask patch-at 1 0
[
    print self
]
```

you get:

```
(patch 4 5)
```

I guess you may have been confused by the fact that, [when using tick-based view updates](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#updates), the view is not updated until [`tick`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tick) (or [`display`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#display)) is called. But it's only the visual representation of your model that is delayed in this case. The underlying *state* of your model is updated as soon as you run a command that has side effects, like `setxy`.

Comment: Yes I have been confused by that fact